# How to flatten a list of lists containing dates in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of valid dates in Python

```
   myList =['05-06-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-07-2015 01-07-2016',   '26-08-2015', '26-08-2016', '23-06-2015 26-08-2016 01-07-2015',   '06-07-2015']
```

As you can see, some elements have a single value, some have two and some have three dates.

My problem is to reduce all of these into a flattened list, which looks like this:

```
    flatList =['05-06-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-07-2016',  
 '26-08-2015', '26-08-2016', '23-06-2015', '26-08-2016', '01-07-2015',  
 '06-07-2015']
```

I tried to do this:

```
flatList  = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(myList))
```

But, this is not behaving as I expected and it is splitting each character as a list.

Can you please let me know how I can accomplish this?

Expected output:

```
    flatList =['05-06-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-07-2016',  
 '26-08-2015', '26-08-2016', '23-06-2015', '26-08-2016', '01-07-2015',  
 '06-07-2015']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `split` each element in your original list and then flatten, e.g.:

```
In []:
list(it.chain.from_iterable(s.split() for s in myList)

Out[]:
['05-06-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-07-2016', '26-08-2015',
 '26-08-2016', '23-06-2015', '26-08-2016', '01-07-2015', '06-07-2015']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split each element and then flatten the 2D list you'll have as a result, or if you want to avoid having to do the flatten bit, you could make your own loop:

```
newList = []
for i in myList:
    newList.extend(i.split())
```

Although I'd like to think that this isn't very pythonic - but it's an answer none-the-less.

Comment: No need to check for space. Split will behave consistently even if it's missing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Correct, but we check for the space because if split is successful, then we need to use `.extend` not `.append`

Comment: the whole point is that you don't need to append. `split` always returns a list that you can extend with, even if it only has one element.

Comment: Looks pretty Pythonic to me

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

my_list = [
    '05-06-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-07-2015 01-07-2016', '26-08-2015',
    '26-08-2016', '23-06-2015 26-08-2016 01-07-2015', '06-07-2015'
]

flat_list = list(chain(*[x.split() for x in my_list]))

print(flat_list)
```

output:

```
['05-06-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-07-2016', '26-08-2015', '26-08-2016', 
'23-06-2015', '26-08-2016', '01-07-2015', '06-07-2015']
```